# How to listen to Apple TV Remote in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, uitapgesturerecognizer, avplayerviewcontroller

This seems like it should be pretty straight-forward but I'm having trouble finding a working example, good documentation, or even many StackOverflow posts that are helpful.

I have a custom view which contains an AVPlayer, like so:

```
@implementation
{
    @private
    AVPlayerViewController *controller
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

(I have a few other views like a message that overlays the player, a poster that I display while swapping videos, etc - but this is the basic setup)

When I integrated the IMA SDK, I started to have issues. If you press the pause button on the remote control during an ad, it pauses the ad just fine. But if you press the pause button ***again*** it doesn't unpause the ad, but instead unpauses my content player behind the ad. I don't hear any audio, but I know the content player was unpaused because I have ID3 metadata in my video and an `NSLog()` statement when I hit it, and I begin to see these logs. If I press the pause button again, the logs pause. I press it a fourth time, the logs start up again.

To try and fix this I wanted to bind a listener to the remote's play/pause button and make sure that if I was playing an ad then the ***ad*** was resumed, not the content. So I tried adding the following to my `init` method on my view:

```
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.view action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [tapRecognizer setAllowedPressTypes:@[ [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPressTypePlayPause] ]];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

I then created the following method:

```
- (void) tapped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

This isn't being called. I'm pretty confident I made a simple mistake, but the documentation isn't very clear, so I'm not sure what I should be doing instead. The [official documentation on detecting button presses](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html) uses Swift and says:

```
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)];
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

I ***believe*** I translated those three lines well. The documentation then doesn't show what the `tapped` method should look like, but instead goes on a tangent about working with low-level event handling. So to get the appropriate method signature I looked at [the documentation on UITagGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) which had the following (Swift) example for writing a handler:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

This is why I went with `- (void) tapped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender`

Still, after all of that, it's not working.

### Quick Update

I tried replacing:

`initWithTarget:self.view`

With:

`initWithTarget:controller.view`

And:

`self.view addGestureRecognizer`

With:

`controller.view addGestureRecognizer`

And this time it looks like something actually happened when I pressed the play/pause button. The app crashed and Xcode gave me the following error:

```
2019-12-17 12:16:50.937007-0500 Example tvOS App[381:48776] -[_AVPlayerViewControllerContainerView tapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10194e060
```

So it ***seems like*** (correct me if I'm wrong):

- The AVPlayerViewController has the focus, not my view
- The gesture recognizer calls the selector on whatever class you register it to, rather than the class that did the registering

So I guess an alternative question to my original would be: How do I allow ***my*** class to handle a gesture on ***some other*** class (e.g. AVPlayerViewController)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The target does not need to equal the view that the gesture recognizer is attached to**. You can set the target to `MyView` but still attach the gesture recognizer to `controller.view`

To work around the `unrecognized selector` crash, you need to make sure you're providing the correct object as the `target` for your gesture recognizer. The way `UIGestureRecognizer` works is that when the gesture is recognized, it will invoke the given `selector` on the given `target` object. In other words, when gesture fires, it's going to perform the equivalent of:

```
[target selector:self];
```

(You seem to be treating the `target` as the view that the gesture will be attached to, which isn't how it works)

So if you implemented `tapped:` on your class `MyView`, then the `target` you pass to the gesture recognizer initializer should be an instance of `MyView`. You probably want to provide `self`, not `self.view`.

Comment: Here's my problem: I want the AVPlayerView to receive the focus and handle 99% of the UI gestures (seeking, changing captions, etc -- all swipes, button presses, and taps should be fed to the AVPlayerViewController for standard video player behavior). However I want the ***parent*** of the AVPlayerView (my view) to intercept and handle play/pause events. Passing my view as the target to the gesture recognizer wasn't working, as noted in my original post, because my view doesn't have the focus. If I give my view the focus, then I can no longer seek or change captions or do anything else.

Comment: The 'target' of a gesture recognizer and who has focus are unrelated. In any case, you can certainly create whatever gesture you want and attach it to whatever *view* you want, including the AVPlayerView. Have you tried something like  `UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)]; [controller.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];` ? (Note the difference between `self.view` vs `self` when creating the gesture)

Comment: That's the secret sauce. I didn't realize that the view I added the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to didn't have to match the `target`. The view I add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to **is** related to who has focus (when I put it on a different view, it never triggered)

Comment: The `target` doesn't need to be a view at all (and usually isn't).